# Should there be a tab in the review pane for 'someone voted to close'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Should there be a tab in the review pane for 'someone voted to close'/'needs close votes'/'partially closed' or something?

It would make finding the partially closed questions a lot easier before they get buried.

Comment: good idea. this would assist the clean up activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal:

What I'll start doing is in the regulators room, I'll start linking some questions that have 1 or 2 votes on them.

[There currently is.](https://askubuntu.com/review/close?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=week)

However, its part of the 10K "mod tools", so most users can't see it.

Comment: so for some of us who need to use it it doesn't exist. any exceptions?? or like station a mod in the room??? 24-7 like maybe yourself?? come-on..... I don't like the answer. dont take it personal

Comment: @BlueXrider I have a solution. Just hang on a moment for my edit.